# Excel VBA:Type misMatch error in using Index and Match functions

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vba

I encounter error in index and match functions when the counter of date changes. I wrote a comment when I face with error. here is the code :

```
Sub regionalAverage()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Application.EnableEvents = False

ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

Dim address(2) As String
Dim rw As Variant
Dim col As Variant
Dim date_ini As Date
Dim date_fin As Date

   'create WorkSheet

date_ini = #1/1/2008#
date_fin = #1/4/2008#
For j = 1 To 3
    For conteo = date_ini To date_fin
        For i = 1 To 2
            With Sheets(i)
                With Application
                 col = .Match(j, Worksheets(i).Range("F2:F23393"), 0)
                 rw = .Match(CLng(conteo), Worksheets(i).Range("D2:D23393"), 0)
                 address(i) = .Index(Worksheets(i).Range("H2:H23393"), col,  rw)
                ' the error appear here
                End With

            End With
        Next i
    '    computation
        area = 6.429571
        Sheets("Output").Activate
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, j).Select
        colname = Split(ActiveCell(1).address(1, 0), "$")(0)
        Columns("" & colname & ":" & colname & "").Select
        Selection.Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
             LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
             MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select

        ActiveCell.Value = "=(SUM(" & address(1) & "," & address(2) & "))/" & area & ""

    Next conteo
Next j

End Sub
```

When the date changes to 1/2/2008 I face with error, how can I solve it ?!

Thank you

Comment: do you mean the line with `address(i) = .Index` ? or after it, the line of `End With` ?

Comment: I mean the line with `address(i) = .Index`

Comment: you declared `Dim address(2) As String` and here when i = 2, then you are looking already at array member 3, and you are getting your error (the address() array start at 0, then 1).

Comment: you mean in `dim address(number) as string`  the number should greater a number than counter i ?

Comment: when you are declaring arrays, you start from 0 (unless you use Redim). and your For i loop start from 1, therefore you have delta of 1 in the counters

Comment: I am confused , would you please mention which line should change !! I change dim to Redim but still I get error. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

made the following changes (marked with ' in the code below)

```
Sub regionalAverage()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

' *** change the declaration here ***
Dim address() As String
Dim rw As Variant
Dim col As Variant
Dim date_ini As Date
Dim date_fin As Date

' *** add Redim here, so the index of the array will start from 1 ***
ReDim address(1 To 2)

date_ini = #1/1/2008#
date_fin = #1/4/2008#
For j = 1 To 3
    For conteo = date_ini To date_fin
        For i = 1 To 2
            With Sheets(i)
                With Application
                    col = .Match(j, Worksheets(i).Range("F2:F23393"), 0)
                    rw = .Match(CLng(conteo), Worksheets(i).Range("D2:D23393"), 0)

                    On Error Resume Next
                    address(i) = .Index(Worksheets(i).Range("H2:H23393"), rw, col)  ' switched between rw (i think it's your row reference) and col

                    ' to help debug the error you get
                    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                        MsgBox "Error number " & Err.Number & " in row " & rw & " Col " & col
                    End If

                    On Error GoTo 0

                End With

            End With
        Next i

    '    computation
        area = 6.429571
        Sheets("Output").Activate
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, j).Select
        colname = Split(ActiveCell(1).address(1, 0), "$")(0)
        Columns("" & colname & ":" & colname & "").Select
        Selection.Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
             LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
             MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select

        ActiveCell.Value = "=(SUM(" & address(1) & "," & address(2) & "))/" & area & ""

    Next conteo
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: what error are you getting now ? can you attach a screen-shot of the error to your original message ?

Comment: @MajidJavanmard ready my message above, please add a screen-shot of the error messgae you are getting. what is the value of `col` , `rw` ?

Comment: Excuse me mr Rado for bothering you. I dont know how to send screen-shot to you. but I uploaded a sample of my file into this link: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00243748825638974221

Comment: just tell me when you scrollover the line with error, what values you get for `col` and `rw` ?

Comment: for 1/1/2008 col=1  , rw=1, for 1/2/2008 col=1 rw=33

Comment: Mr.Rado the results are wrong. may I ask you to download the uploaded file and check it yourself please !?

Comment: Mr.Rado excuse me but I am really in hurry , could you find any solution ?!